# Exclude blank columns and first column in query

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I am looking to return the names from a data set ignoring blank columns and hiding the first row. The problem is it's dynamic so I can't specify "select col2, col3, col4" etc...)

This screenshot is an example sheet of a much more complex system but to my knowledge a working formula should suffice. The requirements are that it looks up the Item and returns the names from the Data Set.

[Link to sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15vim02_kyST9L7McI1LsAfV4BtCdpbJzEUbOVg6xFhk/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: May not be exactly what you want but you may try `=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A4&"♦♥"&B2:4),"♥"),"select max(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1",),,10^7)),"♦ "))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a long method which I am not happy about as I would have thought there would be an easier way. Nevertheless:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({$A$2:$Z4}, "SELECT " & JOIN(",", "Col"&COLUMN(B:G)) & " WHERE Col1 = '"&$A7&"'"))),"ORDER BY Col1 DESC"),1,TRUE))
```

Breaking this down `"SELECT " & JOIN(",", "Col"&COLUMN(B:G))` will select Col2-Col7. The results will still include empty cells so I order the results in descending order (to put empty cells last, behind text values). I then `SORT` the entire thing in ascending order to flip it back to A-Z removing spaces.

For anyone curious...